# Prove that an integer of the form $8n +7$ cannot be expressed as a sum of three integer squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

> Consider an integer of the form $8n +7$.  Show that it cannot be expressed as a sum of three integer squares.

Hints are welcome. If you wish to post an answer, please post a hint as your answer, especially some fundamental concepts in elementary number theory / abstract algebra that might be relevant.

My work, so far:

As noted by carmichael561 (please see his hints below), the problem makes sense only for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Suppose, for contradiction, that

$$8n+7 =  a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$

for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

We can rewrite the equation as $$8n = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 -7$$

Now since $8$ divides the LHS, it also divides the RHS.  In particular,

the LHS is a number that is congruent to $0$ mod($8)$ but the LHS is congruent to $7$ mod($8$), which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: what are the squares mod $8$?

Comment: Hi @carmichael561, I should say that it is not given whether $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Does your hint still apply?  For instance if $n = \frac{1}{2}$, then $8n + 7$ is an integer.  Thanks,

Comment: @user58865 you said three integer squares, so $n=\frac 12$ is not allowed.

Comment: Note that $8\cdot\frac{1}{2}+7=11=3^2+1^2+1^2$. It's safe to say $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Hi @carmichael561, what do you think of my answer (posted as a revision to my question)?

Comment: $a^2+b^2+c^2-7$ doesn't have to be congruent to $7$ mod $8$. To elaborate on my hint a bit, which residue classes mod $8$ are squares? (There are only $3$ of  them.) And can these residue classes possibly be combined to give you $7$?

Comment: If $a^2+b^2+c^2=8n+7$ then $a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv 7$ (mod $8$). So as I've said, the key to arriving at a contradiction is determining the possible residue classes of $a^2,b^2,c^2$ mod $8$.

Comment: I'm pretty stuck on $a^2+b^2+c^2$ $\equiv$ $7$ (mod $8$) @carmichael561.  Can I get another hint?

Comment: Sure: show that the possible residue classes for a square mod $8$ are $0,1,4$.

Comment: Hi @carmichael561, I think I am able to show it now - thanks so much.  Can I just ask you one last thing?  Would $\frac{1}{8}$  be considered having residue $1$ (mod $8$)?

Comment: To determine the residue classes of squares mod $8$, you just need to compute $a^2$ mod $8$ for $a=0,1,2,\dots,7$. There is no need to divide by $8$.

Comment: Yes, @carmichael561, but I thought "mod 8" means to divide by $8$?  Also, I kind of did it a slightly longer way, considering $a = 2k$ (even) and $a= 2k+1$ (odd) and looked at $\frac{a^2}{8}$ to check its remainders, for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3,...$

Comment: Mod $8$ means the *remainder* when the integer is divided by $8$. And since every integer has remainder between $0$ and $7$ (inclusive) when divided by $8$, these are the only cases you need to check.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much for your time and help, @carmichael561.